# Android: Identifying active Bluetooth connections

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there a way that when I start my app, it can figure out if any Bluetooth devices are actively connected to the phone?  I want my app to be able to report on an active BT connection by supplying the BT device name.

I cannot find anything in the BT API that seems to be able to handle checking sockets for activity and reporting on active devices.  Only seem to be able to track such devices if my app stops all active connections and then tries to establish one while it is running.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No - 
The recent API Level 11 introduces APIs to find if A2DP or Headset profile is connected, and to retrieve the connected devices to this profile.