# How to know bluetooth is using

Tags: android

Sometime bluetooth is enabled but no any device connected.  I want to know how to determine no device connected to bluetooth.  The following is example.
1. Headset disconnected.
2. No file transfer.

Comment: Where is the example?, what have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You can just call [getBondedDevices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices%28%29) it will give You all connected devices.
However, I think You might actually need to know not only connected (paired) devices, but if there's any *active connection* with one of them. Unfortunately (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621267/android-identifying-active-bluetooth-connections) seems to confirm it) there's no way to find it out afaik.